# Getting from $N$ to $N-8$ with finitely-many steps of adding $3$ or removing an instance of the digit "$1$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is a strange question that a friend gave to me:

> Suppose we have an $n$-digit number $N$ written on the board. We are given the following challenge:
>
> At every step, we can either add $3$ to the number $N$ and write the new number, or delete one of the instances of the digit "$1$" within the number and write the new number on the board.
>
> Is it possible that after a finite number of steps we have the number $N-8$?

I really don't know where to start from!

I did a little experimenting with some examples but didn't make it :)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: There are examples for specific $N$.  $9, 12, 2, 5, 8, 11, 1$.  I suppose your question is about for arbitrary $N$ however, whether it is true for all $N$ that there always exists a sequence of steps to get to $N-8$.  That said, I assume that $N$ should be restricted to being $9$ or greater to avoid having to deal with negative numbers.  There is obviously no way that starting with $N=4$ that we make it to $-4$ since these modifications always keep the number positive.

Comment: Does it work with longer numbers? With more digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy to describe approach is to start with $N$ which has $n$ digits.  Add $3\ \frac 13(10^n-1)$ times.  This will add $10^n-1$ to the number, which will put a $1$ in front of it and decrease the rest by $1$.  Now cancel the $1$ at the front.  Repeat $8$ times.  This takes more operations than other approaches, but it will work.

Comment: You are a genius!